# Getting a "Adding a value to a 'datetime2' column caused an overflow" only when operating on large dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm basically calculating the difference between two dates in the format days:hours:mins:sec

```
CONVERT(varchar, datediff (s, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff (s, [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate]), CONVERT(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) AS Length
```

Both [CreatedDate], [ClosedDate] are in DATETIME2

If I do:

`SELECT top 10000` then it works as expected

But when I do a `SELECT *`then I get this error:

> Adding a value to a 'datetime2' column caused an overflow.

Is my method not optimal enough? What do I need to change?

Thanks.

Also - The minimum date for both of these is 2015-07-01 so I think this won't apply here: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table ([CreatedDate] datetime2, [ClosedDate] datetime2)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2015-07-01 12:30:00','2015-07-01 12:30:02'),  -- 2 sec
('2015-07-01 12:30:00','2015-07-01 12:35:02'),  -- 5 min 2 sec
('2015-07-01 12:30:00','2015-07-01 17:35:02'),  -- 5 hrs 5 min 2 sec
('2015-07-01 12:30:00','2015-07-02 12:30:00'),  -- exactly 1 day
('2015-07-01 12:30:00','2015-07-02 12:00:00'),  -- 30 min short of 1 day
('2015-07-01 12:30:00','2017-02-06 16:00:00'),   -- more than 1 year
('2015-07-01 12:30:00',null)                    -- Default to current datetime

Select *
      ,Elapsed = concat(DateDiff(SS,[CreatedDate],IsNull([ClosedDate],GetDate()))/86400,Format(DateAdd(S,DateDiff(SECOND,[CreatedDate],IsNull([ClosedDate],GetDate())),0),':HH:mm:ss'))
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
CreatedDate                 ClosedDate                      Elapsed
2015-07-01 12:30:00.0000000 2015-07-01 12:30:02.0000000     0:00:00:02
2015-07-01 12:30:00.0000000 2015-07-01 12:35:02.0000000     0:00:05:02
2015-07-01 12:30:00.0000000 2015-07-01 17:35:02.0000000     0:05:05:02
2015-07-01 12:30:00.0000000 2015-07-02 12:30:00.0000000     1:00:00:00
2015-07-01 12:30:00.0000000 2015-07-02 12:00:00.0000000     0:23:30:00
2015-07-01 12:30:00.0000000 2017-02-06 16:00:00.0000000   586:03:30:00
2015-07-01 12:30:00.0000000 NULL                          586:04:15:59
```

Comment: this actually worked! thank you so much, sir! :)) This is pure gold!

Comment: @90abyss Happy it helped

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl and see if you have the same error...

```
select 
    convert(varchar(16),datediff(ss,[CreatedDate],[ClosedDate])/86400) + ':'+ 
    convert(varchar(16),(datediff(ss,[CreatedDate],[ClosedDate])/3600)%24) + ':'+ 
    convert(varchar(16),(datediff(ss,[CreatedDate],[ClosedDate])/60)%60) + ':'+ 
    convert(varchar(16),datediff(ss,[CreatedDate],[ClosedDate])%60)
where CreatedDate is not null and ClosedDate is not null
```

Side note, you aren't getting the error in `SELECT TOP 1000` because the error doesn't lie in those rows. I think you have a blank value in one of those columns... i.e. white space instead of a `NULL` value and this is causing your addition to fail.

```
declare @d1 datetime2 = '1/1/2017'
declare @d2 datetime2 = ''

select @d1, @d2

select 
    dateadd(s, datediff (s, @d1, @d2),CONVERT(datetime2, '0001-01-01'))
```

Comment: yep! this is working as well now. thanks! :) although i checked there is no white space in those columns - its either NULL or a datetime

Comment: Awesome @90abyss  this seems like you have two solutions